# A Brushfire algorithm to generate a distance map in a grid

Tags: c#, pathfinding

I'm working on implementing a goal-based pathfinding.
first step is to set a goal and calculate the shortest walkable distance between the goal and all points in the grid, using a brushfire algorithm.

I'm worried about two things here, readability and efficiency, since this is for an RTS game.

```
    int[] GenerateHeatMap(IGrid grid, GridPoint goal)
    {
        var heatMap = new int[grid.Cells.Length];
        var unexploredPoints = new List<GridPoint>();
        var openPoints = new List<GridPoint>();
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.Height; j++)
            {
                unexploredPoints.Add(new GridPoint(i, j));
            }
        }

        var currentDistance = 0;
        heatMap[grid.IndexOf(goal)] = currentDistance;
        openPoints.Add(goal);
        unexploredPoints.Remove(goal);
        while (openPoints.Count > 0)
        {
            currentDistance++;
            var newOpenPoints = new List<GridPoint>();
            foreach (var currentPoint in openPoints)
            {
                for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
                    {
                        var point = new GridPoint(currentPoint.x + i, currentPoint.y + j);
                        if ((i == 0 && j == 0) || !unexploredPoints.Contains(point) || newOpenPoints.Contains(point) || !grid.PointToCell(point).CanCross) continue;
                        heatMap[grid.IndexOf(point)] = currentDistance;
                        newOpenPoints.Add(point);
                        unexploredPoints.Remove(point);
                    }
                }
            }
            openPoints.Clear();
            openPoints.AddRange(newOpenPoints);
        }
        return heatMap;
    }
```

For clarity here the definition of GridPoint

```
public struct GridPoint
{
    public GridPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public readonly int x;
    public readonly int y;
}
```

What can I do to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to implement a `HeatMapGridPoints` class and inside this class, create two separate methods for `GetUnexploredPoints` and `GetOpenPoints` which will return list of `GridPoint`. This way, you can expand and also reuse the `HeatMap`. Also, it would be more readable than just gathering them into one method.

Example :

```
public class HeatMapGridPoints
{

    public IList<GridPoint> GetUnexploredPoints(IGrid grid)
    {
        var points = new List<GridPoint>();

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.Height; j++)
            {
                points.Add(new GridPoint(i, j));
            }
        }

        return points;

    }


    public IList<GridPoint> GetOpenPoints(IGrid grid, GridPoint goal)
    {
        // rest of the code 
    }


}
```

you can also do something like this :

```
public class HeatMapGridPoints
{
    private readonly IGrid _grid;

    private readonly GridPoint _gridPoint;

    public IList<GridPoint> OpenPoints { get; private set; }

    public IList<GridPoint> UnexploredPoints { get; private set; }



    public HeatMap(IGrid grid, GridPoint goal)
    {
        _grid = grid;

        _gridPoint = goal;

        OpenPoints = GetOpenPoints(); 

        UnexploredPoints = GetUnexploredPoints();
    }


    private IList<GridPoint> GetUnexploredPoints()
    {
        ...
    }


    private IList<GridPoint> GetOpenPoints()
    {
        ...
    }


}
```

usage :

```
var heatMap = new HeatMapGridPoints(grid, goal);

foreach(var point in heatMap.OpenPoints)
{
    ....
}
```

this would make it much easier to maintain and also more readable.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my code. I'll edit my initial post to explain the brusfire algorithm.

How it works is: set the goal as my start point in my grid, and give it a distance of 0 in my distance map (it's called heatmap but I think distance map is better)
then I set that point as an "open" point.
Then for each point in my open points I get all its neighbours, check if they're walkable and unexplored, set their distance in the heat map, and add them to the list of open points. Then I remove the open points I just treated, and repeat until there are no new open points.

Comment: @user1747281 I understood your code, but don't know the brushfire algorithm except what you have in your code. What I was suggesting is expanding your code (as I suggested) would give you a better management. The idea is an easier way to access both functionalities, and a way to store the points instead of regenerating them every time you call  `GenerateHeatMap`.